# Zend Framework decorator subform add a class tag to DD wrapper tag

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this form:

```
class Request_Form_Prova extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $SubForm_Step = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
        $SubForm_Step->setAttrib('class','Step');
        $this->addSubform($SubForm_Step, 'Chicco'); 

        $PrivacyCheck = $SubForm_Step->createElement('CheckBox', 'PrivacyCheck');
        $PrivacyCheck->setLabel('I have read and I agre bla bla...')
                     ->setRequired(true)
                     ->setUncheckedValue('');
        $PrivacyCheck->getDecorator('Label')->setOption('class', 'inline');

        $SubForm_Step->addElement($PrivacyCheck);


        $SubForm_Step->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'OK',
        ));
    }
}
```

That generate this HTML:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="">
    <dl class="zend_form">
        <dt id="Chicco-label">&nbsp;</dt>
        <dd id="Chicco-element">
            <fieldset id="fieldset-Chicco" class="Step">
                <dl>
                    <dt id="Chicco-PrivacyCheck-label"><label for="Chicco-PrivacyCheck" class="inline required">I have read and I agre bla bla...</label></dt>
                    <dd id="Chicco-PrivacyCheck-element">
                        <input type="hidden" name="Chicco[PrivacyCheck]" value=""><input type="checkbox" name="Chicco[PrivacyCheck]" id="Chicco-PrivacyCheck" value="1">
                    </dd>
                    <dt id="submit-label">&nbsp;</dt>
                    <dd id="submit-element">
                        <input type="submit" name="Chicco[submit]" id="Chicco-submit" value="OK">
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </fieldset>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</form>
```

How can I add a `class="Test"` to the `<dd id="Chicco-element">` element?
In order to have it like that:   `<dd id="Chicco-element" class="Test">`

I thought something like that but **it don't work:**

```
$SubForm_Step->getDecorator('DdWrapper')->setOption('class', 'Test');
```

or

```
$SubForm_Step->getDecorator('DtDdWrapper')->setOption('class', 'Test');
```

How can I do it?
How can I wrap that DD and DT element of a SubForm in another DL element?

Like that:

```
<dl class="zend_form">
  <dl>
     <dt id="Chicco-label">&nbsp;</dt>
     <dd id="Chicco-element">
         <fieldset id="fieldset-Chicco" class="Step">
             <dl>
             .......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add classes that way.  Check out the source file for `Zend_Form_Decorator_DtDdWrapper` starting on line 67:

```
return '<dt id="' . $elementName . '-label">' . $dtLabel . '</dt>' .
    '<dd id="' . $elementName . '-element">' . $content . '</dd>';
```

You could extend the decorator with your own class, and rewrite the render method to add the classes to the tag.